# Python generating xml file by python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, ipython

The image below is the result of performance testing. One of my issue is: How can I transfer my result into a XML file?

[image: testdata]

I've been trying file writing method. But what if the data I need to parse is massive? Is there a method or plugin to done it with a smarter way?

My code so far:

```
def generate＿xml(jank_perc):

with open('jankyresult.xml','a') as f:
    f.write('<?xml version="1.0" ?>\n')
    f.write("<root>\n")
    f.write("   <doc>\n")
    f.write("      <Jankyframes>" + jank_perc + '%' + "</Jankyframes>\n")
    f.write("   </doc>\n")
    f.write("</root>\n")
```

I don't want to create  manually. I hope there is a smarter way to do it. Thanks for answering!

Comment: You can use jinja2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). An example of it is,

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree, cElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

root = ElementTree.Element('root')
child1 = ElementTree.SubElement(root, 'doc')
child1_1 = ElementTree.SubElement(child1, 'Jankyframes')
child1_1.text = jank_perc

print ElementTree.tostring(root)
tree = cElementTree.ElementTree(root) # wrap it in an ElementTree instance, and save as XML

t = minidom.parseString(ElementTree.tostring(root)).toprettyxml() # Since ElementTree write() has no pretty printing support, used minidom to beautify the xml.
tree1 = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(t))

tree1.write("filename.xml",encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: "tree = cElementTree.ElementTree(root)"
Can you maybe explain this code for me? Thanks, I really don't know why it's here.

Comment: `The cElementTree module is a C implementation of the ElementTree API, optimized for fast parsing and low memory use. On typical documents, cElementTree is 15-20 times faster than the Python version of ElementTree, and uses 2-5 times less memory` according to effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm  added a comment in front of that code as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I've notice the use of ElementTree.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [yattag](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yattag/) library:

> Generate HTML or XML in a pythonic way. Pure python alternative to web template engines.Can fill HTML forms with default values and error messages.

Here's an example based on your code sample:

```
doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()

doc.asis('<?xml version="1.0"?>')

with tag('root'):
    with tag('doc'):
        with tag('Jankyframes'):
            text(jank_perc + '%')

with open('jankyresult.xml','a') as f:
    f.write(doc.getvalue())
```

Depending on how you get your input data (e.g. a `list` or `dict`), you could iterate over it and write your results to the XML while still keeping the code readable.